# Bash reads .bashrc despite being non-interactive, somehow caused by ssh

Tags: bash

Given GNU bash, version 5.0.3 (Debian Buster), given the following `.bashrc`

```
echo "Hello from .bashrc"
```

and executing the following commands while being logged in via SSH

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
[...]
> cd /tmp
> bash -c 'echo $-' > log  &
> cat log
Hello from .bashrc
hBc
```

seems to indicate that Bash is reading and executing `.bashrc` despite not being an interactive shell. (No `i` in `$-`.) According to the man page of bash, `.bashrc` is *the individual per-interactive-shell startup file*, so the file should be ignored.

The behaviour is as expected (no `Hello from .bashrc` in the output) when the shell command is started synchronously (`bash -c 'echo $-' > log`) instead.

The behaviour is also as expected when I try this using GNU bash, version 4.3.30 (Debian Jessie) and starting the command asynchronously:

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
[...]
> bash -c 'echo $-' > log &
> cat log
hBc
```

Moving `/etc/bash.bashrc` out of the way and executing `bash -x -c 'echo $-' &` gives the following output:

```
$ bash -x -c 'echo $-' &
[1] 10578
$ + echo 'Hello from .bashrc'
Hello from .bashrc
+ echo hxBc
hxBc
```

If I `strace` the bash invocation in question, the following list of files is reported as being opened:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/bash.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/net/homes/myuser/.bashrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

So I'm fairly sure that no other files are somehow interfering.

It only seems to happen when sshing into the host, but not when executing the command locally. If I unset the environment variable `SSH_CLIENT`, the odd behaviour goes away.

Is this a bug in Bash or Ssh, or is this something with my local configuration?

---

Steps to reproduce:

```
# from host:
docker run --rm -it -p8022:22 --name bashrc_tmp debian:stretch

# inside container:
apt update
apt install -y openssh-server
sed -re 's/^#?(Port 22)/\1/' \
     -e 's/^#?(ListenAddress 0\.0\.0\.0)/\1/' \
     -e 's/^#?(PermitRootLogin ).*$/\1 yes/' \
     -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc/init.d/ssh start
echo 'echo "hello from .bashrc"' > ~/.bashrc
chpasswd <<<'root:hi'
```

```
# from host: (password is 'hi')
ssh root@localhost -p 8022 true
ssh root@localhost -p 8022 -o RemoteCommand=true
ssh root@localhost -p 8022 -T true
ssh root@localhost -p 8022 -T true </dev/null

# tidy up:
docker rm -f bashrc_tmp
```

All of these invocations of `ssh` will show the "*hello from .bashrc*" message.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `.bashrc` isn't sourced by `bash -c`.

Comment: Me neither (At least with GNU Bash 4.3.30).

Comment: @chepner using which version of bash? I just realized that this only happens with Debian Buster (bash 5), but not with Jessie (bash 4).

Comment: Are you sure your `.bashrc` isn't being included by something else? If you move / remove it do you get an error? What does `bash -x -c 'echo $-'` show?

Comment: @Attie If I move `.bashrc` away I don't get an error and no output. But this is to be expected, the file is optional anyway.

Comment: This indicates that something is including it explicitly... what about the output of `bash -x ...`? This is probably a local configuration issue.

Comment: @Attie See updated question.

Comment: I can't repro in a fresh Debian Buster image in Docker. Bash 5.0.3(1)-release

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for trying. What happens when you ssh into the image? The behaviour seems somehow related to ssh as well.

Comment: `( strace bash -c 'echo $-' & wait ) |& grep openat` - my bash doesn't try read `/etc/bash.bashrc` nor `.bashrc`

Comment: "_It only seems to happen when sshing into the host, but not when executing the command locally_" ... this statement is very relevant, and I can reproduce this behaviour... even using `ssh -T` and `ssh -o RemoteCommand=...`, `.bashrc` is still evaluated. I'm not sure why, sorry.

Comment: @Attie Thanks for the reproducer. At least I'm now sure its not caused by my local configuration.

Comment: Getting `sshd` to run inside Docker requires a couple of iffy hacks. Starting an interactive Bash over SSH and then running `bash -c 'echo $-'` still does not repro for me, nor does `ssh -p 2222 tripleee@localhost 'echo $-'`, nor `ssh -p 2222 tripleee@localhost bash -c 'echo $-'`

Comment: @triplee - I agree with your first point, however your latter points exhibit the behaviour for me even when targeting a physical machine (i.e: not docker). I see an the output of an `echo` that I've added to my `~/.bashrc`. Also worth noting that this particular system has an [escape mechanism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ45N.png) at the top of `~/.bashrc`, as shipped by Ubuntu.

Comment: The same hack is there on Debian and IIRC always has been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a long time bash contains code trying to detect if it is run by sshd, and then sourcing bashrc as needed (only showing relevant code here):

```c
static void
run_startup_files ()
{
  /* ... */
  int run_by_ssh;

  /* get the rshd/sshd case out of the way first. */
  if (interactive_shell == 0 && no_rc == 0 && login_shell == 0 &&
      act_like_sh == 0 && command_execution_string)
    {
#ifdef SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC
      run_by_ssh = (find_variable ("SSH_CLIENT") != (SHELL_VAR *)0) ||
                   (find_variable ("SSH2_CLIENT") != (SHELL_VAR *)0);
#else
      run_by_ssh = 0;
#endif

      /* If we were run by sshd or we think we were run by rshd, execute
         ~/.bashrc if we are a top-level shell. */
      if ((run_by_ssh || isnetconn (fileno (stdin))) && shell_level < 2)
        {
          /* ... */
          maybe_execute_file (bashrc_file, 1);
          return;
        }
    }
/* ... */
}
```

The define `SSH_SOURCE_BASHRC` is enabled on Debian for both bash-4 and bash-5.

Now, the difference in behaviour was introduced in bash version 5.0-alpha. The Changelog contains the following note:

> This document details the changes between this version,
>   bash-5.0-alpha, and the previous version, bash-4.4-release.
>
> 1. Changes to Bash
>
> [...]
>
> f. Fixed a bug that caused SHLVL to be incremented one too many times
>      when creating subshells.
>
> [...]

And indeed, when executing `echo $SHLVL` (which reflects the contents of the variable `shell_level` above) I get `2` for bash-4 and `1` for bash-5.

But additionally this change regarding `SHLVL` seems to have an unwanted side effect: invoking bash asynchronously no longer increases the value of `SHLVL`.

```
# Bash 4
> echo $SHLVL
2
> bash -c 'echo $SHLVL' 
3
> bash -c 'echo $SHLVL' & wait
3
```

vs

```
# Bash 5
> echo $SHLVL
1
> bash -c 'echo $SHLVL' 
2
> bash -c 'echo $SHLVL' & wait
1
```

This explains the change in behaviour, and it also explains why unsetting the environment variable `SSH_CLIENT` helps to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

After the discussion and reproducing this issue, I actually **looked** at the `~/.bashrc` file that I was adding an `echo` to the very top of, and found the following. I'd suggest you do something similar.

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

This is an escape mechanism, which is present in the default `~/.bashrc`, as shipped by Debian and Ubuntu (see `/etc/skel/.bashrc`), and probably others...

If `-i` is in `$-` then we continue processing `~/.bashrc`, otherwise it bails out.

---

Fedora has something similar in `/etc/bashrc` (sourced by the template `~/.bashrc`), which means that your user's `~/.bashrc` will always be ingested, but the system's configuration will not.

```sh
# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Hah, I very nearly did that too, but decided not to for *reasons*...

Comment: I'll do that with the `.bashrc` I'm having issues with. Thanks. But this still doesn't explain *why* it tries to read that file, despite not being an interactive shell.

Comment: Agreed, please come back and answer if you figure it out!